# what does this line mean on my ps aux ../apache2 -k start

Tags: apache, shell, nginx, apache2, ps

I am running a web server using nginx but i can see apach2 lines when i type

```
ps aux | grep apache
```

The result it looks like this :

```
www-data  3280  0.0  1.1  99708 45204 ?        S    14:11   0:09 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  8651  0.0  0.9  99708 36120 ?        S    18:32   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root      9428  0.0  0.0   3408   764 pts/0    R+   19:04   0:00 grep --color=auto apache
www-data 23048  0.0  0.0   3728  2172 ?        S    04:00   0:00 /usr/bin/ruby /usr/lib/collectd/plugins/apache_ps -h 01-6PMO317H3OSIK
www-data 26491  0.0  1.1 101252 46308 ?        S    06:30   0:22 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 26492  0.0  1.2 105120 50316 ?        S    06:30   0:23 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 26493  0.0  1.1  99708 46660 ?        S    06:30   0:24 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 26494  0.0  1.1 103436 47148 ?        S    06:30   0:23 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 26495  0.0  1.2 103304 48524 ?        S    06:30   0:22 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 26685  0.0  1.1  99708 45236 ?        S    06:38   0:23 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28435  0.0  1.1  99708 43916 ?        S    08:06   0:19 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 30950  0.0  1.1  99716 44672 ?        S    10:12   0:16 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     31480  0.0  0.6  97400 26544 ?        Ss    2013   1:22 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

What is this about ?

Comment: Apache2 come pre-installed with many distributions. If you want to only use ngix, you can remove apache

Comment: i agree, but what does it mean /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start ?

Comment: It is the command that was used to start the apcahe2 process. There are many possible options i.e. `-k start|restart|graceful|stop|graceful-stop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every line with `/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start` represents the command that started an apache process with the argument `-k start` to run a new instant of apache

Apache2 comes by default with many distributions, you can remove it if you only want `ngix`